# How can I use a Lambda bool method within a WHERE clause?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a method `IsMatchingRegex` which will return `true` or `false`. I want to check whether the Lambda property matches against the `IsMatchingRegEx`. If it does match, it should be added to the `validItems` List. How can I make the Lambda Expression work without changing the TRUE/FALSE method?

```
validItems = items.Where(x => x.Sub.PropertyToCheck == IsMatchingRegex(x.Sub.PropertyToCheck))
```

Comment: What do you mean by *whether the Lambda property matches against the IsMatchingRegEx*? What is the type of `x.Sub.PropertyToCheck`?

Answer (score 2):

Why compare equality to the property? Just:

```
validItems = items.Where(x => IsMatchingRegex(x.Sub.PropertyToCheck));
```

The [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a predicate that given an item of the collection returns for it `true` or `false`. If you method already does that - just call it.